# C# Generice type inference

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I have an extension method like this:

```
 public static class Extensions
    {
        public static TOut To<TIn, TOut>(this TIn value)
        {
           .......
        }
    }
```

but when I want to use it, compiler can not infer the input parameter type:

```
var i = 0;
var res = i.To<decimal>(); //compiler error, because compiler can not infer the TIn type that is integer
```

the curios part is that when I am using method `To` without opening the `<` the compiler shows that `TIn` is `integer`, but when I open the `<`, compiler asks for `TIn` too.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to put both as far as I know or leave both off if it is inferred. You can't do half (e.g. <decimal>).

Comment: @MikeCheel Idid same in VB.NET and it works perfectly fine

Comment: @Arsalan  C# has different rules.  All type parameters must be specified, or they must all be inferred.  There's no middle ground.